# get data from database with out query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net

Is there any way to retrive data from Database with out writing any sql query . I mean i want to read data into my label fileds with out writing any query in sqlcommand.Please anyone help me or tell me how can i do this in c# or vb.net

**Update**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Test\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
         SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);        
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Test", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Test");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();        
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: using LINQ is also similar to querying the database. To get the data from database we need to send the request. and that request is your select statement which will give you results as per the query.

Comment: Jedi Magic... summon your inner force.

Comment: Can you use a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to write direct SQL queries, then another option is ORMs like:

1. [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx)
2. [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx)

Here's a related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505/what-are-your-favorite-net-object-relational-mappers-orm

Depending on how much database interactions you need, you may find the few lines to execute a SQL command query directly easier.  If you need to do quite a bit of DB interactions with objects then an ORM may be more productive for you.

Code samples are outside the scope of a question because you need to setup mappings etc... but here's a getting started with tutorial:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You might want to find an ORM.

**Linq to Sql** and **Entity Framework** are a couple you can use out of the box in .Net.

Comment: You'll need to create a datasource in your .Net project to use either, then objects based on your SQL tables/views will be generated for you to use in your code. There are many examples for both Linq 2 Sql and EF on the web.

Comment: Linq to SQL tutorial: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq to sql. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) is a some examples

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not sure I understand your question, but I do not think there is a way to get 'any' data from DATABASE without querying. You may have to use a simple select query to return the data from a table or a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Framework 2.0 doesn't support LINQ! U can't use entity framework or LINQ in framework 2.0. Try framewerk 4.0. If not u have to write a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Strongly Typed DataSet File and then return data into your label